# 400 Bad Request - PHP Curl JSON request

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm getting 400 Bad Request when Im trying to send a request to a server in php.

Using this API -

https://sandbox.dropship.provet.com.au/orders

"CREATE ORDER" call.

Code is -

`<?php
//set POST variables
$username='user';
$password='pass';

$url = 'https://sandbox.dropship.provet.com.au/api/orders';

$fields = array(
                'CustomerName' => 'Customer Name',
                'AddressLine1' => 'Customer Name Address',
                'Suburb' => 'Albany',
                'State' => 'Perth',
                'Postcode' => '6330',
                'Country' => 'Australia',
                'CustomerEmail' => 'customername@gmail.com',
                'CustomerPhone' => '9425361366',
                'OrderLines' => array('ProductCode' => 'ACTI SO 10', 'Quantity'=>1),
                );

$data_string = json_encode($fields);

echo strlen($data_string); exit();


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , FALSE);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === false)
{
  // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
  print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
  exit();
}

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_r(json_decode($result));

?>

</pre>`

How do i resolve this problem??

Comment: i can't try it, because i haven't credentials there. have you tried another content-type? to make sure, the api works as you expect, i suggest to use a tool like Fiddler. Then you can send your post request with the data.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller As API supports JSON & XML media types. I've sent request with JSON content type. I can't provide credentials. 
I will try it Fiddler. Thanks

Comment: i read that too, but i think thats the accept type. so you'll get json or xml back. and maybe you have to send the data urlencoded. as stated [here](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1) urlencoded is the default for posting forms.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller Tried with urlencode form fields too. Getting same response. I have doubt in created array for request, specially in 'OrderLines' property.